# TYPO3 OpenGraph with EXT:news

Tags: templates, typo3, facebook-opengraph, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 and News System and Bootstrap Package.

I see the opengraph tags twice. One of the news and one of page. How i can resolve it?

Comment: sorry, i'm new. i edited the qestion

Comment: as most of us are new, we all have to learn what is possible (with our current ranking) and what is the common way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to exclude the opengraph of the bootstrap package when being on a news detail page. Then you only get it once.

Put this into your TypoScript

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    page.meta.og:title >
    page.meta.og:site_name > 
    page.meta.og:description > 
    page.meta.og:image >    
[global]
```

Comment: Thank you for youw answer. How can i do that?

Comment: Can i ask you where i can find a good documentaion about the sintax?
For Example:
" page.meta.og:title > " exclude the tag but i don't undertarnd why and if i want change the og:title? I think i have to write "page.meta.og:title = something" but it doesn't work.
I tried to find the documentation but i found different syntax.
Sorry, excuse ignorance

Comment: this can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Meta/Index.html. just use "docs typo3 page meta" in google

Comment: yes i read it.
But when i write "page.meta.og:title = something i want" the page show the page title and not 'something i want'

Comment: you can always use the TypoScript Object Brower to check the final values of your TS. Additionally use "page.meta.og:title >" before your declaration to clear any properties set before

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Georg for the hint. For TYPO3 version 9 you should use new typoscript condition syntax:

```
// Prevent bootstrap_package og:attributes for single view
[(request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0]
    page.meta.og:title >
    page.meta.og:site_name >
    page.meta.og:description >
    page.meta.og:image >
[end]
```